# how to run script on remote machine with delay

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux, remote

I want to run script on remote machine but with delay

for example

```
 scp -rp script root@$IP:/tmp

 ssh root@$IP:/tmp/script   ( but script will run after 5 sec )
```

the target is to run the script with no connection from source machine ( not via ssh ) , so ssh will be only the trigger and after 5 sec script will run

Comment: This might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30400/execute-remote-commands-completely-detaching-from-the-ssh-connection

Just add a `sleep 5` to the start of your script

Answer (score 1):

You can upload a loader script that starts your script after a delay and then run it with the following command to run it remotely:

`screen -d -m loader.sh`

**Loader.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1
script.sh
```